# Notice Period Query

Tags: resignation

My contract says I must give one months notice. I gave notice on 17th Aug, stating my last working day would be Friday 11th Sept, which is 4 working weeks. But my employer says I must work till 17th September.Is this correct and can they hold me to this?

Comment: Voting to close, since this is specific to your contract, but it seems pretty clear that your contract says 1 month, not 4 weeks.

Comment: Do you have any holiday left? Perhaps use that as a bargaining chip

Comment: Why do you think you should not have to work the "one months notice" from your contract, can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want to define correct and hold, probably. 1 month should imply that if you resign on day X of a month, then you work until the X of the next month with a few exceptions, e.g. if you resigned on January 30th then there isn't a February 30th though one could work out roughly what is 30 days later. Also, don't forget you don't state what jurisdiction you live and this is a global site as I'm in Calgary, Alberta, Canada for what it is worth.

Their Math would be the 17th of August plus one month is the 17th of September while you have the expectation that 4 weeks would be the equivalent but that isn't quite true. 12 months at 4 weeks a month would imply 48 weeks to a year which isn't correct. Thus, you are ignoring the additional days that should be added here as unless you resigned in February there will be extra days to factor here.

Answer (score 0):

Check your contract, and if in doubt the consult a legal professional.

If your contract says 1 month, your final day of work would be the 17th (or perhaps 16th, since the day you give your notice is typically inclusive). One month is one calendar month, which takes you to the equivalent date of the next month. This can get a little more complex since some months are shorter than others, but that's probably not relevant in your case as August is a longer month.

Many people's contract says 4 weeks, and we'll often describe that as one month's notice, but in terms of your contract it's a very different thing.

In short, your boss is right. So the real question is what to do about it

You may be able to apologise for the misunderstanding and ask if s/he would be willing to waive a few days of the notice period, this will entirely depend on your boss.

You may also wish to check your annual leave allowance: for example I've recently given 4 weeks notice but have 5 accrued days of leave which I haven't taken, so I can essentially reduce my notice period by taking those at the end of my notice period if I wished (although beware of anti-compete or 'no other employment without permission' clauses in your contract)

If you have no saved up holidays, and your boss doesn't agree, you have little choice but to either work the notice period (the 'correct' option), or choose to break your contract or call in sick etc. Both of the latter carry their own potential legal and moral implications and I don't recommend them.